# PrestaShop - How to retrieve Carrier ID in Smarty during the checkout process

Tags: prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.5

I am using PrestaShop 1.5.3.1 and I want to retrieve the Carrier ID during the Payment step in the checkout process.

In PrestaShop 1.4 I was using `{$id_carrier}` and it was working just fine, but it is not working in PrestaShop 1.5.x

I want to show one payment method depending on selected carrier.

For example:

```
{if $id_carrier == 1}
    my content
{/if}
```

Comment: Did you take a look at the smarty debug console to see if there is any variables that could be useful?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the payment page, you can retrieve the selected Carrier ID using the following Smarty variable:

```
{$cart->id_carrier}
```

This will work anywhere in the Front-end, both on PrestaShop v1.4.x and v1.5.x.

```
{if isset($cart->id_carrier) && $cart->id_carrier == 1}
   {* Do some stuff here *}
{/if}
```

Comment: If we are talking about \controllers\front\payment.php, this is not working if user didnt change the carrier on 4th order step - the value wasnt updated, so is 0 - need to use (int)Configuration::get('PS_CARRIER_DEFAULT');

Answer (score 2):

`$carrier = new Carrier($cart->id_carrier); // in payment module page`