# Prestashop display content based on selected carrier ID

Tags: prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7

My question is very similar to this already existing one:

[Prestashop get carrier id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946376/prestashop-get-carrier-id)

I'm trying to display a input form, depending on the selected carrier in prestashop 1.7's 'shipping method' step.

I've tried the following:

```
{if $cart->id_carrier == '25'}; 
{if isset($cart->id_carrier) && $cart->id_carrier == 25};
{if $delivery_options item=carrier key=carrier_id == '25'};
{if $carrier->id == '25'}
{if $delivery_option == '25' and $carrier_id == '25'}
{if $delivery_option == '25'}
```

None of which resulted in the form displaying. To clearify it again, I'm trying to display it in the same step, in which the customer is selecting the carrier option.

Answer (score 0):

In Prestashop 1.7 it seems to be `$carrier.id` rather than `$carrier->id`.